# How to show AdCell for every three cells of table view in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, row, uicollectionviewcell

I have to show Adcell for every three cells after. for that I have taken two prototype cells and designed adcell in one and normal cell in other

**code:** with my code only after first three rows `AdCell` showing and lost 3rd row from `JobsCell` from 4th row data showing

**how to show Adcell for every cells and without losing `JobsCell` data.** please guide

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return categoryData?.result?.categoryData?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var returnCell: UITableViewCell!

if indexPath.row == 3  {
    returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdCell", for: indexPath) as! AdCell
}

else {
    returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobsCell", for: indexPath) as! JobsCell
    returnCell.selectionStyle = .none
}
return returnCell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   var count = categoryData?.result?.categoryData?.count ?? 0
   return count + count / 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var returnCell: UITableViewCell!

if indexPath.row % 3 == 0 && indexPath.row != 0  {
    returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdCell", for: indexPath) as! AdCell
}

else {
    returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobsCell", for: indexPath) as! JobsCell
    returnCell.selectionStyle = .none
}
return returnCell
}
```

Comment: with above code I am facing 2 issues
1)now also each time `AdCell` replaces `JobsCell` not showing in separate row why? where is wrong
2)first time after three JobsCell got  AdCell and then for every two JobsCell got AdCell

Comment: could you check the above mentioned issues and try to update answer please

Answer (score 1):

The first problem: in your example `func(numberOfItemsInSection)` returns less rows than need. Therefore, to begin with, adding the missing cells.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   let n = categoryData?.result?.categoryData?.count ?? 0

   //for example here 10 jobs
   //3j 1a 3j 1a 3j 1a 1j(last) Here 3ads
   //10/3 = 3(and 1)
   //so will 11/3=3(2), then 12/3=4(0)
   //So generic formula: num = j + j/3

   let num = n + n/3   //n is Int so division rounds the number down

   return num
}
```

Second problem: when adding an extra cell in `indexPath`, it gonna lost fourth job if using data[indexPath.row].
So it possible to create variable like "jumpDownNumber". It will save the step to the skipped `indexPath.row` number.

```
var jumpDownNumber = 0 //and reload it before tableView.reloadData()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   var returnCell: UITableViewCell!
   
   //after 3 jobCell is every fourth AD cell

   if (indexPath.row+1) % 4 == 0 {
      returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdCell", for: indexPath) as! AdCell
      jumpDownNumber += 1
   } else {
    returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobsCell", for: indexPath) as! JobsCell

    //here you can use data[indexPath.row-jumpDownNumber]
    returnCell.selectionStyle = .none
   }

   return returnCell
}
```

Comment: your answer looks bit confusing.. I have tried above @santhosh answer and facing below issues.. according to that answer could you fix the issues.. plase

Comment: I am facing 2 issues with @santhosh answer. 
1)now also each time AdCell replaces JobsCell not showing in separate row why? where is wrong 2)first time after three JobsCell got AdCell and then for every two JobsCell got AdCell

Comment: cant we fix the issue without using `jumpDownNumber`?

Comment: If you set all values in tableViewCell class, there will always be skipped one cell from the Jobs array. And the jumpDownNumber won't even help. Alternatively, in the Jobs array, you can add extra "blank data" in the gaps that will be skipped. If there is no display of line numbering. 2) ```if n % 3 == 0``` will be through 2 cells, not 3. Cause rows starts from 0. Need a formula for counting the sequence [3, 7, 11, 15...]. Here is:```if (n+1)%4 == 0```